# How to properly use struct inside for loop?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, struct

Task: We need to create 7 structure objects called parent[1-7] using loops. Then make user input for their name, age, child name. Afterwards 1) print name of the parent that has the biggest family. 2)print longest child name for the parents with shortest name (compared to other) I know, sounds confusing already. And 3) Print out all the given info of parents (name, age, child name/names) that are older than average of 7 parents age.

Problem: I bumped into the trouble that I can't even setup this right for program to scan user input. I have added a new `struct` object and `scanf` for user to insert how many kids he has, for easier access later on, but it keeps crashing when I enter that number for example 2 or 3 kids. To be honest, I have no idea how to do other parts of this task.

This is how program looks at the moment (I'm on my first year in University, so I expect that I made some mistakes):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int max=3;
int j=0;


struct parents
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
    int kid_count;
    char kid_name[30];
};

int main()
{
  for(j=0; j<max; j++)
  {
    struct parents parent[7];
    parent[j].name;
    parent[j].age;
    parent[j].kid_count;
    parent[j].kid_name;


    printf("Parent %d Enter parent name \n",j+1);
    scanf(" %s", &parent[j].name);


    printf("Parent %d Enter parent age \n",j+1);
    scanf(" %d", &parent[j].age);


    printf("Parent %d Enter how many kids he has \n",j+1);
    scanf(" %d", &parent[j].kid_count);


    printf("Parent %d child name \n",j+1);
    scanf(" %s", &parent[j].kid_name);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `&` when reading strings. The compiler should have warned you about it too.

Comment: Change it to a fixed length array `struct parents parent[j];` => `struct parents parent[7];`. 
You're creating a j-sized variable length array on each iteration. You can't access element `[j]` in a `j`-sized array. `j-1` is the last element.

Comment: `struct parents parent[j];` - what this line is supposed to do? It is a *definition* of array `parent` of length `j`. Pretty sure you want to define it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(j=0; j<max; j++)
{
    struct parents parent[7];
```

You're declaring an array of 7 structures here, each and every time through the loop. Because it's declared on the stack in the scope of the loop's body, that array will also go away each and every time through the loop. But you only ever use one of the structures, i.e. the one at index `j`, on each iteration.

What you probably mean to do instead is to declare the array outside the scope of the loop, so that it persists after the loop is done.

```
    parent[j].name;
    parent[j].age;
    parent[j].kid_count;
    parent[j].kid_name;
```

These lines don't seem to do anything. Did you mean to assign a value to each field here? The next thing you do is to write values into those fields using `scanf()`, so any value that you might set here would be overwritten. Probably best to just delete these lines.

```
 return 0;
}
```

Once the loop is done, nothing else happens. Even if you move the array of `parent` structures outside the loop, it's going to go out of scope at this point without anything being done with it. To make that array useful, you need to *use* it. Maybe you just haven't gotten to that part yet?

Comment: Can you tell me more on that last part? How do i actually store those variables, so i don't loose them once the loop is done? Sorry for dumb questions.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Indeed, made adjustment and changed max to 3 for testing purposes, to spend less time writing all the char's. Right now i moved struct before the loop and faced other problem: now i need to compare name lengths and after the loop print out the parent with longest and shortest name, but have no idea how to do it

Comment: @RichardTheProgrammingNewb If you move the array of `parent` structs outside the loop, then it'll still be available to use when the loop is finished. If you leave it inside the loop, then not only will it not be available when the loop is done, but the entire array will also be destroyed and recreated *every time through the loop*. In general, a variable declared inside a set of braces (`{...}`) goes away after the closing brace.